# Knitting a ggplot causing figure-html/ not found in resource path: pandoc conversion error 99

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a plot that works just fine in R console and even in RMarkdown code chunk. However i can't knit the RMarkdown file with it. I've tried so long to find a solution and rewritten the code a hundred times but can't figure it out.

Here is the plot code.
NOTE the csv just has 2 columns, year & installs (amount of installs)

````
```{r ## line graph to show rate of installs over time - last 50years}
installs_per_year_50years <- read_csv("installs_per_year_50years.csv", col_types = cols(year = col_date(format = "%Y-%m-%d")))

t <- copy(installs_per_year_50years$year)
z <- copy(installs_per_year_50years$installs)

plot_installs_over_50 <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = installs_per_year_50years, aes(x=t, y=z, group=1), color="red", stat="identity")+
  labs(title = "Number of New Public Art Installations per Year", subtitle = 'Including installations outside of the areas and those in multiple areas', x = "Year", y ="New Public Art")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,75,by=5))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 6, angle = 90))
plot_installs_over_50
````

[here's the output that works everywhere else except for the knitting.][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7qZi.png

Here's the error it generates from the knitting process:

```
output file: ANAL.knit.md

/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/quarto/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS ANAL.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output ANAL.html --lua-filter /cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --variable bs3=TRUE --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --template /cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=united --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --include-in-header /tmp/RtmpzJEYg6/rmarkdown-str1d491176a8db.html 
**File ANAL_files/figure-html/ not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
Execution halted**

ANAL means analysis lol sorry bad naming.
I'm using R 4.2.1
I have checked my directory and all files are in the same place. cloud/project
the only other folder was created by knit cloud/project/ANAL_files/figure.gfm
this is the sample plot generated the rmarkdown template.

This is my first project so help is appreciated.

the folder
```

Answer (score 1):

I just asked my colleague about this same error and this worked for me: add `self_contained: no` into your html specification:

```
output:
  html_document:
    theme: cerulean
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    keep_md: yes
    self_contained: no
```

lmk if it works!

Answer (score 0):

OMG I spent like 4hours trying to debug this for myself.
Randomly decided to put the code for the plot below a previous plot's code and it fully decided to knit correctly. I have no idea why it wants to only live below that 1st plot though. It wasn't even near it, it was in a whole other section of my doc.

If anyone knows why this happened I'd love to know. Here is the other plot's code, the one that my problem plot didn't work if placed ahead of it.

```r
p <- ggplot(data = Unique_art_per_poparea, 
aes(x=Freq, y=Var1, fill=rownames(Unique_art_per_poparea))) +
geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
guides(fill="none") + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,280,by=20)) +
geom_text(aes(label=Freq), hjust=-.5, color="black", size=2.5) +
labs(
  title = "Number of Public Art Installations per Population Area", 
  subtitle = 'Including installations outside of the areas and those in multiple areas', 
  x = "Number of Public Art Installations", 
  y ="Population Area"
)

p
```

Comment: I been building an rmarkdown html document too and was getting the pandoc error too and was struggling to find the issue and found this thread and it worked but why?   Using self_contained = no makes the final product look terrible!